Is the second-quantized density-density interaction positive-definite?
Typically in the textbook of second-quantization, we say that that if the system interacts via density-density interaction $V(r)$, then the second-quantized form of the interaction is
$$\hat{H}=\int dr_1 dr_2 V(r_1-r_2) c^{\dagger}_{r_1}c^{\dagger}_{r_2}c_{r_2}c_{r_1}\tag{1}$$
Where $c$/$c^{\dagger}$ is the fermion field operator
Now there seems to be another commonly-used version in the literature, i.e.
$$\hat{H}'=\int dr_1 dr_2 V(r_1-r_2) c^{\dagger}_{r_1} c_{r_1} c^{\dagger}_{r_2}c_{r_2}.\tag{2}$$
I understand by using the commutation relation, we can prove that the first and the second only differ by a quadratic term that looks like
$$\hat{H}'-\hat{H}=\int dr c^{\dagger}_{r}c_{r} V(0).$$
Now what confuses me is that given $V(r)$ always positive, it is obvious that $\hat{H}'$ is positive definite, that is for any many-body state, $\langle \Psi|\hat{H}'|\Psi \rangle$ is greater than zero. On the other hand, $\hat{H}$ is not positive definite.
Then why are the first one the standard definition? Why shouldn't we use the second one since presumably we want the energy for a repulsive interaction to be always positive? Or is it the case the the $H$ is actually positive definite but I missed it?

I want to make a slightly different point than the other answer. The important point is that second quantization, especially when restricted to a sector of Fock space with fixed particle number, is equivalent to first quantization; it is just a matter of convenient notation. In first quantization, with $N$ particles, $\hat{H}$ can equivalently be written as
$$
\hat{H} = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq N} V(\hat{r}_i - \hat{r}_j)
$$
whereas $\hat{H}'$ can be equivalently written in first quantization as
$$
\hat{H}' = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq N} V(\hat{r}_i - \hat{r}_j) = \hat{H} + N V(0)
$$
The difference between these two is purely in whether $i = j$ terms are contained in the sum or not. In other words, these two interactions simply differ by whether self-interactions are included or not. It is a good exercise to show that the second-quantized Hamiltonians you wrote are equivalent to the first-quantized ones I wrote; for example, show that they have the same action on properly symmetrized position eigenstates (this then proves that they are equal as operators, since the position eigenstates form a complete basis).
Even if $V(0)$ is finite, one typically does not include self-interactions in the two-body interaction term of a Hamiltonian, whether it is written formally in first or second quantization. Thus, $\hat{H}$ is somewhat more correct than $\hat{H}'$. Of course, if $V(0)$ is infinite, then you have no choice: $\hat{H}$ is the correct version.

take myow upvote

But is it able to prove that H is postive definite?

Why don't you just prove it directly?  Take any arbitrary state $\vert \Phi\rangle$ and try $\langle \Phi \vert c_1^{\dagger} c_2^{\dagger} c_2 c_1 \vert \Phi \rangle$, and convince yourself that this is non-negative.

You are focusing on the wrong thing. It is not +ve-definiteness that is important here. It is that $$\int\vec{\mathrm d^3r}\,\hat c_r^\dagger\,\hat c_r\,V(0)=\infty$$
I mean, the operator part is obviously the number operator and will do just fine, but the usual potential to consider as $V(\vec r)$ is the Coulomb potential $V(\vec r)=\frac1{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{qQ}{|\vec r|}$ and it is this quantity that diverges when you consider zero distance.
That means that $\hat H^\prime$ is always infinite, and to get suitable results, you must first do baby renormalisation on this expression, and that is why we always start with $\hat H$; this quantity is guaranteed to be zero when you only have one single particle.
